# Re-sign.jar gives me error signing apk Ubuntu

Tags: android, apk, signing

I have been trying to test apk file by resigning them and learnt about re-sign.jar drag and drop tool for signing apks. I am trying to run it using terminal on Ubuntu but it always says JAVA-HOME not set. My eclipse is working, AVD is working, adb is working then whats an issue with this? Please help.

Have a look at the error:

[image: screenshot of error]

`java -version` in terminal gives me:
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: You might try `sudo -E` to keep the environment. But you should not need `sudo` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Setting the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It may returns something like:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      manual mode
```

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

The path of the installation is for each:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Copy the path from your preferred installation and then edit the file /etc/environment:

sudo nano /etc/environment
In this file, add the following line (replacing YOUR_PATH by the just copied path):

```
JAVA_HOME="YOUR_PATH"
```

That should be enough to set the environment variable. Now reload this file:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Test it by executing:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If it returns the just set path, the environment variable has been set successfully. If it doesn't, please make sure you followed all steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to sudo because normally a jar signing tool won't need it. Try `java -jar re-sign.jar` instead. When you add sudo, JAVA_HOME is not set.

You can do some experiment, in terminal:

```
Krypton@Krypton:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Krypton@Krypton:~$ sudo -s
root@Krypton:~# echo $JAVA_HOME

root@Krypton:~#
```

So in sudo mode, JAVA_HOME is NULL, that's why you got the error message. If you insist running it with sudo:

```
root@Krypton:~# sudo -E java -jar re-sign.jar
```